# TypeError: encoding without a string argument when sending a data with an discord bot in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make an discord bot that sends a txt file with text in it. I already tried to do this with the io moduke with the BytesIO class. on following code you can see what i have already tried.

```
proxies_formated = 'Whats up'
content = bytes(str.encode, proxies_formated)
await message.author.send(file=discord.File(BytesIO(content), f"{message.author.id}.txt"))
```

But I got the following error:

```
     content = bytes(str.encode, proxies_formated)
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content = proxies_formated.encode()
```

is how you convert str to bytes.

*Side note: its spelled "formatting", with 2 t's.*